# GIT - Moving commits to different repository

Tags: git, github, repository, git-merge, git-subtree

I have this specific requirement in our project infrastructure.

We have a project A with git repository location as

> ssh://xyz.com:/A.git

Due to project requirement we had to split the modules from project A (with sub-directories/modules b,c,d,e,f) into two different git repository which are on different location and sub-directories/modules are also renamed (i.e. b become b1 etc).

New repositories and structures are as given below: 
a. Project A1 (having sub-directories/modules b1, c1 and d1) with repository location

> ssh://yyy.com:/A1.git

b. Project B1 (having sub-directories/modules e1, f1 and g1) with repository location

> ssh://zzz.com:/B1.git

But during this transition we were working on repository A and we have many commits  for modules b,c and d which are missing from repository A1 on sub-directories/modules b1, c1 and d1.

We would like to restored the missing commits of sub-directories/modules b,c and d from repository A into modules b1, c1 and d1 on repository A1.

We tried merge sub-tree and read-tree options but due to sub-folders renaming it is not working for me. Could anyone please guide me in resolving this problem.

Comment: Have you tried designing a scenario with tree-ish and commit-ish commands. I have not used them personally, but I think they may be useful for you

Comment: So are you saying you have already tried merging but the merge conflicts were too complicated?

Comment: Massey101, When i am doing read-tree with -u/-m option and --prefix with a particular folder, It is giving me error as "overlaps  to" and "cannot bind" message for already existing files/classes. Seems somehow it is not able to merge the content of the files.